# Imcremental data import in Power BI Desktop table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In my Power BI desktop model, I have a fact table with 10 million rows.
Every day, I need to add (import) 600,000  new rows to this fact table inside Power BI desktop from SQL server data warehouse.
My concern is how can I incrementally import these new data and add it to the already existing one in my Power BI Desktop model.
Simply refresh data will read every day all the 10 million rows which will be time consuming.

I tried to modify the M code of the fact table to get new rows after a specific date but this solution completely erase the already 10 million rows of the fact table in Power BI Desktop.

Below my M code

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("10.Xx.Xx.Xx", "MY_DB"),
    dbo_fact_table = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="fact_table"]}[Data],    
    filteredRows = Table.SelectRows(dbo_fact_table, each [date] >= StartDate)
    
in
    filteredRows
```

Comment: Not possible in PBI Desktop to do incremental refresh, that’s a service only option

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for Power BI Desktop, then you can disable `Include report refresh` on the query which has the 10M rows. Right-click on your original query and deselect `Include report refresh`.

Then create a second query for the new rows, and create a third query that appends the two queries with any desired row duplication removal. For the last bit of removing duplicates, the order is important, so ensure when you are appending, you are appending the 10M rows query to the bottom of the new rows query.